# how I can erase from memory the scene and meshes? Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am adding "n" number of circles on the scene.

```
var radius = 1; 
var segments = 32; 
var circleGeometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry( radius, segments); 
function generateCircles(){
  //scene.remove(circle);
  var count=0;
  while (1000> count) {
   circle = new THREE.Mesh (circleGeometry, material);
   scene.add (circle);
   count ++;
  }
}
```

It is effective to do it this way ?.

in my code I call this function. and every time you call it, it all goes back slower, I guess it's because there are more objects in the scene. what can I do?

Each time the function is called I need erased completely from the memory stage and the circles that were generated.

with "slower", I mean that I want my application to run faster. every time I run the function add more and more circles. so I want to be removed earlier. to add new ones. if there are many circles in the scene it slows execution.

http://jsfiddle.net/v8oxsxtc/

Comment: What do you mean "it all goes back slower"?

Comment: @SimpleJ with "slower", I mean that I want my application to run faster. every time I run the function add more and more circles. so I want to be removed earlier. to add new ones. if there are many circles in the scene it slows execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the old circles from the scene by calling the `scene.remove` method on each of the circles you previously added. Here is a simple example using your code:

```
var lastCircles = null;
function generateCircles(){
  var count=0;
  if(lastCircles) { // remove old circles if they exist
    lastCircles.forEach(function(c) {
      scene.remove(c);
    });
  }
  lastCircles = []; // clear cache
  while (1000 > count) {
    circle = new THREE.Mesh (circleGeometry, material);
    lastCircles.push(circle); // add each circle to cache
    scene.add (circle);
      circle.position.set(count,count,count)
    count ++;
  }
}
```